# Picking values from a variable

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk

I have a variable in my shell script that looks like this:

```
DIR="HOME_X_Y_Z";
```

It represents a directory name. Imagine I have multiple directories all named something like this:

```
HOME_1_2_Z/
HOME_9_A_Z/
HOME_3_5_Z/
etc...
```

The only values that change are those located at position *X* and *Y*. Is there a regular expression I could use (maybe with sed or awk) to peel those values out? I want to be able to used them independently elsewhere in my script.

So I would be able have 2 more variables:

```
X_VALUE="";
Y_VALUE="";
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very easy with pure bash:

```
IFS='_' read X_VALUE Y_VALUE Z_VALUE <<< "${DIR#*_}"
```

Explanation:
So, `${DIR#*_}` is going to remove the shortest match from the beggining of the string. See [parameter expansion cheat sheet](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) for more stuff like that.

```
echo ${DIR#*_} # returns X_Y_Z
```

After that all we have to do is change the default IFS to `_` and read our values.

Comment: I can mark this as answered in 6 minutes, job done though. Cheers buddy!

Comment: # removes the shortest match, not the longest.

Comment: It would be simpler to discard the prefix with a dummy variable, i.e., `IFS=_ read _ X_VALUE Y_VALUE Z_VALUE <<< "$DIR"`.

Comment: that's what I meant, Thanks!
@chepner yeah, that's why there are several answers :)

Answer (score 4):

Set IFS and use `read`:

```
IFS=_ read home x y z rest <<< 'HOME_X_Y_Z'
echo "$y" # "Y"
echo "$z" # "Z"
echo "$x" # "X"
```

Comment: That is a great answer as well, but some people might freak out about ``home`` part. Also, you have forgot to quote your variable and place a ``$`` mark as well. It must be ``<<< "$HOME_X_Y_Z"`` and ``echo "$y"``

Comment: @Aleks-DanielJakimenko Well, the input is supposed to be a literal string, but you're right about the rest. Thanks! Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to fiddle with IFS you can still do it in pure Bash by stripping off the parts you don't want, but it's not a one-liner:

```
DIR2=${DIR#HOME_}
DIR2=${DIR2%_Z}      # $DIR now contains just X_Y
X_VALUE=${DIR2%_*}
Y_VALUE=${DIR2#*_}
```